How to redirect output to file with timestamp?
Myscript will run every day and it will delete the old files.
create the file where I want to redirect output
echo myproj-"date+ %Y-%m-%d"

Now from cli
jf rt del (some files) > how to specify my file here
Every day, it be will different,because of the timestamp.
How to add this?

"My idea": this makes all no sense. I think you mean echo myproj-$(date +%Y-%m-%d) instead (notice the parentheses and the position of the +), and your jf rt del ( …)  makes no sense either. "how to specify my file here": Which file? You haven't mentioned any file! You can't redirect files, you redirect outputs; do you maybe mean that you want to redirect some output to some file?
Because all this is not clear, it's also not clear what you really want to do, I'm afraid. Please describe in clear words what you need to do.

thanks for the edit! echo doesn't create a file. Also, you don't have to create a file to redirect output into; that will happen when you do the redirection. I think my problem was that you're using "file" where you mean "file name", is that possible? You want to "calculate" a file name.

You can use a command substitution in a file redirection:
jf rt del … > "myproj-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"

